# Complex query with Mongo

Tags: mongodb, monk

I think the problem is simple to understand but I couldn't find a good solution to it.

In the system the users have some preferences, and the weight of this preference, for example:

```
{_id: ,
 name: "John",
 preferences: [{sku:"Golf", weight: 3}, 
               {sku:"Football", weight: 4}, 
               {sku:"Basketball", weight: 3}]
}
```

So, if a feed will be generated for the user, for each 10 requested news, it will be needed to have 3 basketball, 4 football, and 3 golf news. So, in my News collection I need to have some query supporting pagination that will give me the results always in this user's pattern, considering the weights.

Considering the news collection to be simply like this:

```
{ _id: ,
  text: "A really nice Hole in One after a par"
  category: "Golf" 
},
{ _id: ,
  text: "Real Madrid wins"
  category: "Football" 
},
...
```

The query must give me the news based on the user weights and support some pagination, nowadays I'm using the `$each` but is tremendely ugly and might have a very bad performance, any suggestions?